# What is the functional derivative of a function depends on derivative at boundary

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

I have the following problem:
There is a functional $I[f]$:
$$I[f]=\int_{-1}^1\Bigl(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=-1}-\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=1}\Bigr)f\mathrm{d}y$$
where $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=-1}$ is $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}$
at ${|y=-1}$.

My problem is to find its functional derivative.

The variation of the functional is
$$\delta I=I[f+\delta f]-I[f]=\int_{-1}^1\Bigl(\frac{\mathrm{d}(f+\delta f)}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=-1}-\frac{\mathrm{d}(f+\delta f)}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=1}\Bigr)(f+\delta f)\mathrm{d}y-\int_{-1}^1\Bigl(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=-1}-\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=1}\Bigr)f\mathrm{d}y$$
Neglecting second order terms, this leads:
$$\delta I=\int_{-1}^1\Bigl(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=-1}-\frac{\mathrm{d}(f)}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=1}\Bigr)\delta f\mathrm{d}y +
\int_{-1}^1\Bigl(\frac{\mathrm{d}(\delta f)}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=-1}-\frac{\mathrm{d}(\delta f)}{\mathrm{d}y}_{|y=1}\Bigr)f\mathrm{d}y.$$
To obtain the functional derivative is trivial for the first integral. In the case of the second integral, I failed. If it contained the derivative function instead of the derivative at certain locations, it would be easy with applying integration by parts. In this case, I have no idea.
Could anybody provide suggestions to solve this problem?